# Is it feasible to highlight realtime "edit" changes?

Tags: feature-request, edits, live-refresh, diff

While reading I see a lot of those "An edit has been made to this post, click to update" gray info bars, but unless the change involves adding a chunk of text, I'm not usually perceptive enough to note the change.

I figured that since the actual body of the question/answer is modified, isn't it possible to gently highlight the edits, for example with dotted underlines, strikeouts, or background color changes?

Comment: I don't think it's feasible, but I have wished for the same on several occasions.

Comment: This is already shown in the "revision history", so showing it on the post itself shouldn't be too hard :-P

Comment: I've put an answer, to bump, but mainly because I think this would be a good idea, especially with the other feature request.

Answer (score 2):

I came here to post the same suggestion. Had the idea when reading this:
[Show edit notification at bottom of posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288561/show-edit-notification-at-bottom-of-posts/288562#288562)

I think reading longer posts will be greatly improved with a combination of this feature request and the one linked above.

- A better notification for new edits when reading a long post - the
  notification and reload button is present wherever on the post you
  are
- Highlighting new text so we can see exactly what was added

Reading the edit history is not really a good means of reading a post IMO.

So, clicking the "new edit" button wherever you are on the post, with the new text being highlighted, you can quickly scroll up to see if there is anything new in what you previously read because it is highlighted.
If no new text in what you've already read, find where you left off and continue reading, the new edit text will simply be highlighted and in the text you've not yet read.